# How to add own audio to a jar file when you export it

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, jar, pathname

I made a simple program where you will just click on a button and a .wav song will play. I made a folder called wav where I store to music. When i make this a runnable jar file I want the music to be part of the program, also I would like a way to change the path of the song so it will take it from the jar file and not a library. My code is:

```
package music;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Music {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
JFrame j = new JFrame();
JButton b = new JButton("Set sail");
j.add(b);
b.addActionListener( new AL());
j.setVisible(true);
j.pack();
j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}}

public class AL implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputStream in;
    try {
        String wav = "C:\\Users\\Mike\\workspace\\music\\wav\\One.wav";
        in = new FileInputStream(wav);
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

So basically I want the .wav file to be a part of my runnable jar file for playing and what the new path name would be for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "file->export->runnable" to export jar files.

In that case you can use relative path such as

```
String wav = "music\\wav\\One.wav";
```

Comment: When i export it to make the runnable jar it doesn't bring the music file with it. Thank you for the path part though :).

Comment: You can music as a source folder Eclipse. See stackoverflow.com/questions/24354921/how-to-add-own-audio-to-a-jar-file-when-you-export-it/24354985?noredirect=1#comment37657646_24354985